# Use third-party dll in ATL project

Tags: visual-c++, com, atl

I have got a C++ unmanaged dll. I have no sources of this dll and I need to use it in ATL project

But I always get an error "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLID {id} failed due to the following error: 80040154 class not registered"

I have tried to register that dll using regsvr32, but no success
I have read lots of tutorial, but all they explain how to created ATL project from scratch. And they do not use ordinary dlls

How can I solve this?

Comment: There is no evidence that what you are trying to achieve is what the DLL is really intended for. Yes some COM registration is assumed. Multiple possible problems, e.g. missing static link dependency.

Comment: @Roman R. Thank you for your answer. This dll works in usual c++ project. And I have to use it in ATL project. It's a big old atl project. I can't rewrite it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my previous ATL project were 32-bit. And everything was working fine.

This project was 64-bit.
I've found out that Visual Studio has a bug:
[MSBuild ignores linker option "Register Output: Yes" for x64 Platform](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/801327/msbuild-ignores-linker-option-register-output-yes-for-x64-platform)

**Workaround 1** (from the link above):

```
<Target Name="RegisterOutput"
         Condition="'$(EmbedManifest)'=='true' and '$(LinkSkippedExecution)' != 'true' and (('$(Platform)' == 'x64' and ('$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)' == 'AMD64' or '$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432)' == 'AMD64')) or '$(Platform)' == 'Win32')">
```

**Workaround 2** (I had C# project in the same solution, so I've used this one):

Add `regsvr32 path_to_cpp.dll` to post-build event

**Note:** you should not add regsvr32 to pre-build as it will not always execute (another source of problems)

From MSDN:

> Pre-build events do not run if the project is up to date and no build is triggered.